In a Stacked Line Chart, is there a way to stack multiple Y-Axes to match each graphed line in Apache echarts?

I want to re-create something like this with Apache echarts . A single x-axis and stacked y-axis .
I am building a project where i have to stack multiple control-charts each chart also having their own mean , upper-limit and lower-limit.
Please do let me know if this is possible. Thank you.
